# MongoDb upsert exception invalid BSON field

Tags: java, mongodb, upsert

This exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name id
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonWriter.writeName(AbstractBsonWriter.java:516)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeMap(DocumentCodec.java:188)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:131)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:45)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
    at com.mongodb.connection.UpdateCommandMessage.writeTheWrites(UpdateCommandMessage.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.connection.UpdateCommandMessage.writeTheWrites(UpdateCommandMessage.java:43)
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseWriteCommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(BaseWriteCommandMessage.java:129)
    at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.encodeWithMetadata(RequestMessage.java:160)
    at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.sendMessage(WriteCommandProtocol.java:220)
    at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.execute(WriteCommandProtocol.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.connection.UpdateCommandProtocol.execute(UpdateCommandProtocol.java:64)
    at com.mongodb.connection.UpdateCommandProtocol.execute(UpdateCommandProtocol.java:37)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:168)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:289)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.updateCommand(DefaultServerConnection.java:143)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$Run$3.executeWriteCommandProtocol(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:490)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$Run$RunExecutor.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:656)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$Run.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:409)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:177)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:168)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:422)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:413)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:168)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:74)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:845)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:828)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:550)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.update(MongoCollectionImpl.java:542)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.updateOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:381)
    at org.hpms.gis.MongoDbTest.insert(MongoDbTest.java:63)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

is thrown by the following code:

```
     final UUID     id        = UUID.randomUUID();
     final double   frequency = 8_000.0 + ( 10_000.0 * Math.random() );
     final double   startSec  = 100*i;
     final double   startNano =  10*i;
     final double   endSec    = startSec  + ( 100*i );
     final double   endNano   = startNano + ( 10*i );
     final double   latitude  = ( 180.0*Math.random() ) -  90.0;
     final double   longitude = ( 360.0*Math.random() ) - 180.0;
     final Document trackID   = new Document(
        "id", new Document(
           "msb", id.getMostSignificantBits ()) .append(
           "lsb", id.getLeastSignificantBits()));
     final Document track = new Document(
        "id", new Document(
           "msb", id.getMostSignificantBits ()) .append(
           "lsb", id.getLeastSignificantBits())).append(
        "frequency", frequency    ) .append(
        "start", new Document(
           "seconds", startSec    ) .append(
           "nanoSec", startNano   )).append(
        "end", new Document(
           "seconds", endSec      ) .append(
           "nanoSec", endNano     )).append(
        "position", new Document(
           "latitude" , latitude  ) .append(
           "longitude", longitude )).append(
        "padding", new byte[1000-8-8-8-4-4-4-4-8-8] );
     //_collection.insertOne( track );
     _collection.updateOne(
        trackID,
        track,
        new UpdateOptions().upsert( true ));
```

The commented code `_collection.insertOne( track );` executes fine.

**Why the insert is fine when the "upsert" is not?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`updateOne` for updating document fields using update operators. You need `replaceOne` which takes the replacement document.

```
_collection.replaceOne(
        trackID,
        track,
        new UpdateOptions().upsert( true ));
```

More here

Update Operators: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-field/

Update One:https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/

Replace One: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/

Answer (score 3):

Another option is `setOnInsert`, as shown in the document of MongoDB:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/

**The operation works only when `upsert` is `true`.**

In your case, you should put fields not to be modified in a document, and fields to be updated in another document, and in the third document, prepend `$setOnInsert` and `$set` as key, respectively.

A big advantage of `$setOnInsert` is that when inserting, it will perform `$setOnInsert` **and** `$set` part, but when updating, only `$set` will be executed.

For example, we have a document to insert/update, which has 5 fields: `name`, `age`, `gender`, `createAt`, `updateAt`.

- When I do a query by field "name" and find no match, I want to insert the document with 5 fields, and fill `createAt` and `updateAt` with current datetime.
- When I do a query by "name" and find a match, I want to update `name` and `updateAt` with current datetime.

What I do is:

```
query = Filters.eq("name", nameToSearch);
Document upsert = new Document();
Date now = new Date();

//only fields not mentioned in "$set" is needed here
Document toInsert = new Document()
        .append("age", newAge)
        .append("gender", genderString)
        .append("createAt", now);
//the fields to update here, whether on insert or on update.
Document toUpdate = new Document().append("name", nameToSearch)
        .append("updateAt", now);

//will: 
// - insert 5 fields if query returns no match
// - updates 2 fields if query returns match
upsert.append("$setOnInsert", toInsert)
        .append("$set", toUpdate);

UpdateResult result = collection.updateOne(query, toUpdate, 
    new UpdateOptions().upsert(true));
```