# Invalid BSON field name

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I looked up similar answers to this question but unable to find any.

```
public void update(String id, String user) {
    Document document = Document.parse(user);
    UpdateResult result = database.getCollection("user")
            .updateOne(Filters.eq("_id", new ObjectId(id)), document);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

My JSON payload looks like this.

```
{
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Doe",
    "email": "john@example.com",
}
```

**Error**

> Invalid BSON field name first

if I remove first from the payload, it objects on the last and so on.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43711716/2683814

Comment: just use replaceOne instead updateOne

Answer (score 7):

`updateOne(Filters.eq("_id", new ObjectId(id)), document);`
This  is  caused  by  your  document format
`updateOne({here  is condition }, {here is operation})`

The document does't have any operation in it ,so it caused this error.
You should put it like this:

```
database.getCollection("user")
        .updateOne(Filters.eq("_id", new ObjectId(id)), combine(set( <field1>, <value1>), set(<field2>, <value2> ) ));
```

Here is the [official  document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/)

In your case, you can try to use replaceOne() with  your code
like

```
collection.replaceOne(eq("item", "paper"),
       Document.parse("{ item: 'paper', instock: [ { warehouse: 'A', qty: 60 }, { warehouse: 'B', qty: 40 } ] }"));
```